# Changing Background Color with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-color

I need to change the background of one of my main container divs with Javascript. The end goal is to apply a gradient but I'm having issues just changing background color. Here's the code:

```
var main = document.getElementById("main");
  main.parentNode.style.maxWidth = 0;
  main.parentNode.style.maxHeight = 0;
  main.parentNode.style.margin = "0px";
  main.style.backgroundColor = "black";
```

This is what the tag looks like in the browser once the page loads and the JS executes.

```
<div id="main" style="z-index: 10; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: black;">
```

I am not getting any JS errors. The JS is executing bc other code runs and the background color is changed in the code but not rendered. The browser I am most concerned about is Safari but I am getting the same effect in Chrome. Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hz7AR/

Comment: Could you provide a demo please?

Comment: @ExceptionLimeCat the code seems to be fine, I dont see any typos or errors. A demo in jsfiddle would help.

Comment: What other CSS do you have for that element? (In your stylesheet)

Comment: Does the element have anything in it? Maybe you just can't see it.

Comment: Could you please open the Developer tools and hover over the specific div. Is it highlighted correctly (light blue overlay)

Comment: Are the children of `main` absolutely positioned or the overflow of `main`s parent hidden.

Comment: Seems to work fine in jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/UEWga/ assuming that's the correct HTML (or near enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the width and height of your div. Currently the div has no width or height change your html to:

```
<div id="main" style="z-index: 10; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: black; height: 100px; width: 100px">
```

That code makes the div 100 x 100 pixels you can set it to whatever you like

Comment: I tried giving the div a fix height and width but that did not work

Answer (score 4):

you are setting the parent container to maxWidth 0 and maxHeight 0. i think there is the problem